# How to send request to backend spring rest controller with a json requestbody and request param as a multipart image file

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, multipartfile

I am writing a backend api which consumes a json request with multipart image files. I am unable to figure out a way to do so.
Anyone, faced and found a solution to a problem similar to mine...???

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Spring Controller endpoint accepting a DTO and a MultipartFile parameter

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/svc")
public class MyController {

  @PostMapping
  public String create(
    @RequestPart(name = "dto") Dto dto, // my Java DTO
    @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
  
}
```

You should be able to use `MultipartFile[] files` if you need to consume multiple files.